# How is $\lvert f\rvert=\int^1_0\lvert f\rvert dx$ not a norm (f is a regulated function, or funtion with bounded variation 0)

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

How is $\lvert f\rvert=\int^1_0\lvert f\rvert dx$ for $f\in R[0,1]$ where R are the regulated functions (bounded variation zero, for an epsilion I can give you a step function where the suprememum of the |difference between a step function and the function|<=epsilion, not a norm.

Yet the next exercise has me show that that $C[0,1]$ does have a norm with this definition.

I'm not sure how to do the || double thing, sorry, I hope you can work out what I mean.

This is self learning

Comment: It is not positive definite. ie. There is a function $f\in R[0,1]$ such that $\|f\| = 0$, but $f\neq 0$. This kind of thing cannot happen for a continuous function.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I thought of that but it's the integral of the absolute value.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I don't quite follow, could you flesh out how that can be in an answer please? It need not be an answer, but it'd be easier to read than comments.

Comment: If $f$ is nonzero only for isolated points, $\int \lvert f\rvert = 0$, but $f$ is not (necessarily) the zero function.

Comment: @DanielFischer but then it's not regulated. Do you mean something like f(x)=0 if x!=0 and f(x)=1 when x is 0, is that regulated?

Comment: What is the definition of a regulated function?

Comment: @DanielFischer a function of bounded variation zero, bounded variation is sort of like a measure of how much it jumps, as you probably know. =sup(sum(|f($x_i$)-f($x_{i-1}$)|)) taken over all subdivisions of the domain (a=$x_0 < x_1 <...<x_{n-1}<x_n=$b)

Comment: Bounded variation = zero means constant. That can't be it.

Comment: @DanielFischer I can see clearly that f(x)=0 x<0 with f(x)=1 else has bounded variation 1. Not sure if that jump is tiny. Also no, bounded variation being zero does not mean the function is constant, it may be, but it need not be.

Comment: @DanielFischer I did say "taken over all possible subdivisions" so it an be thought of as "the sum of the largest difference between the function and 'the point immediately after it'" which is usually 0 (continuity) but if it jumps....

Comment: If the variation of a function is zero, that function is constant. If $f(x) \neq f(y)$, then $\operatorname{Var}(f) \geqslant \lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert > 0$ for every interval containing $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Wikipedia says a regulated function is a uniform limit of step functions. A function with only finitely many points where a non-zero value is assumed is a step function.

Comment: @DanielFischer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation I also don't see what you mean? If it jumps from zero to a non-zero value it will not be regulated? It must be continuous?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11557/discussion-between-daniel-fischer-and-alec-teal)